# How to find the run time of this algorithm to find if a binary tree is balanced?

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree

This is the algorithm

```
int getHeight(node *root)
{
    if(!root) return 0;
    return max (getHeight(root->left), getHeight(root->right)) + 1;
}

bool isBalanced(node *root)
{
    if(!root) return true;
    int balanceFactor = abs( getHeight (root->left) - getHeight(root->right) );  //O(logn)
    if(balanceFactor > 1) return false;
    return isBalanced(x->left) && isBalanced(x->right); //T(n) = 2T(n/2)
}
```

My understanding:

```
//n is the number of nodes in the tree
```

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(logn) as I have mentioned in the comments. But, I can't solve this recurrence. The master theorem doesn't work for this.

The expected runtime for this algorithm is O(N-squared). How is that so? I have got the recurrence wrong, that's for sure.

Comment: `getHeight()` is O(n) not O(log n)

Comment: Also, the recursive calls to `isBalanced` will only take `T(n/2)` if the tree is balanced, otherwise they could take more or less than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about your recurrence relation, but my simple understanding is as follows:

The complexity of your getHeight() function is O(N), because the function gets called for each node in the sub-tree rooted at root once.

By similar reasoning, in the worst case, your isBalanced() function also gets called for each node (N times). Also, at each call, you compute getHeight() function twice.

```
Hence the complexity of isBalanced() function = O( N * (2 * N) ) = O(N^2)
```